# Icon for workspaces on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, workspaces, gnome-shell

I want icon for workspace in the menu.

I understand that workspaces will be added when needed in a vertical column, if you don't need it you have only one plus the next possible.

Answer (score 0):

You may try a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called [Workspace Indicator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/21/workspace-indicator/).

It puts an indicator on the top bar showing in which workspace you are, and gives you the possibility of switching to another one.

[image]
(screenshot source: extension's homepage at extensions.gnome.org)